# "Enhancing WordPress Plugin: User-Friendly Custom Code Integration in Login Section"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I intended to use direct redirection to the registration page instead of displaying the message "Please register before logging in." I have also located the functions responsible for displaying this message and used `wp_redirect` to achieve direct redirection instead of displaying the message. However, I didn't achieve the desired outcome. I am providing the code snippets for your reference.

```
if (!$user) {
    do_action('digits_login_user_not_found', $login_type);
    throw new DigitsNoticeException(__("Please signup before logging in.", "digits"));
}
```

```
if(empty($email)){
    $email = '';

    $check_request = digits_check_request($countrycode . $mobileno, $email);

    if ($check_request instanceof WP_Error) {
        wp_send_json_error(array('message' => $check_request->get_error_message()));
    }

    if ($digit_gateway == 1 || $digit_gateway == 13) {
        $result = 1;
    } else {
        $result = digit_create_otp($countrycode, $mobileno, $request_type);
    }
    $data['code'] = $result;
    digit_send_json_status($data);


    die();
} else {
    digit_send_json_status(array(
        'code' => -11,
        'message' => __('Please signup before logging in.', 'digits')
    ));
    die();
}
```

```
$level = 2;
if (is_wp_error($user_obj) || !$isValid) {

    if (empty($user_obj)) {
        $level = 1;
        $invalid_message = __("Please signup before logging in.", 'digits');
        wp_redirect(home_url('https://www.hamiarad.com')); 
        exit;
    } else if (is_wp_error($user_obj)) {
        $invalid_message = $user_obj->get_error_message();
        /*
            * TODO: remove this when digits are used instead of wp forgot pass page
            * */
        $wp_lostpassword_url = wp_lostpassword_url();
        if (strpos($invalid_message, $wp_lostpassword_url) !== false || $user_obj->get_error_code() == 'invalid_username') {
            $invalid_message = __('Invalid Credentials!', 'digits');
        }

        if ($user_obj->get_error_code() == 'notice') {
            $level = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

```
if (empty($user)) {
    wp_send_json_error(['message' => __('Please signup before logging in.', 'digits'), 'notice' => true]);
}

if (empty($user)) {
    wp_redirect('https://www.hamiarad.com');  
    exit;
}
```

I expected my issue to be resolved using the `wp_redirect` function, but the code is not being executed at all.